# SQL Server from XML parameter to table - working with optional child nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

On SQL Server 2008 R2, I am trying to read XML value as table.

So far, I am here :

```
DECLARE @XMLValue AS XML;
SET @XMLValue = '<SearchQuery>
    <ResortID>1453</ResortID>
    <CheckInDate>2011-10-27</CheckInDate>
    <CheckOutDate>2011-11-04</CheckOutDate>
    <Room>
        <NumberOfADT>2</NumberOfADT>
        <CHD>
            <Age>10</Age>
        </CHD>
        <CHD>
            <Age>12</Age>
        </CHD>
    </Room>
    <Room>
        <NumberOfADT>1</NumberOfADT>
    </Room>
    <Room>
        <NumberOfADT>1</NumberOfADT>
        <CHD>
            <Age>7</Age>
        </CHD>
    </Room>
</SearchQuery>';

SELECT 
    Room.value('(NumberOfADT)[1]', 'INT') AS NumberOfADT
FROM @XMLValue.nodes('/SearchQuery/Room') AS SearchQuery(Room);
```

As you can see, `Room` node sometimes get `CHD` child nodes but sometimes don't.

Assume that I am getting this XML value as a Stored Procedure parameter. So, I need to work with the values in order to query my database tables. What would be the best way to read this XML parameter entirely?

**EDIT**

I think I need to express what I am expecting in return here. The below script code is for the table what I need here :

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE(
    ResorrtID INT,
    CheckInDate DATE,
    CheckOutDate DATE,
    NumberOfADT INT,
    CHDCount INT,
    CHDAges NVARCHAR(100)
);
```

For the XML value I have provide above, the below Insert t-sql is suitable :

```
INSERT INTO @table VALUES(1453, '2011-10-27', '2011-11-04', 2, 2, '10;12');
INSERT INTO @table VALUES(1453, '2011-10-27', '2011-11-04', 1, 0, NULL);
INSERT INTO @table VALUES(1453, '2011-10-27', '2011-11-04', 1, 1, '7');
```

`CHDCount` is for the number of `CHD` nodes under `Room` node. Also, how many `Room` node I have, that many table row I am having here.

As for how it should look, see the below picture :

[image]

> Actually, this code is for hotel reservation search query. So, I need
>   to work with these values I got from XML parameter to query my tables
>   and return available rooms. I am telling this because maybe it helps
>   you guys to see it through. I am not looking for a complete code for
>   room reservation system. That would be so selfish.

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the touch on the title. I am not sure that it a good title here. If you can provide a better title, feel free to change it pls.

Comment: What do you want your destination table of parameters to look like?  Do you care about the child information, or jsut the number of ADT per room?  is NumberofADT the count of child rows?

Comment: Could you give a clearer description of the outputs required - which values do you need and how do you need to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select S.X.value('ResortID[1]', 'int') as ResortID,
       S.X.value('CheckInDate[1]', 'date') as CheckInDate,
       S.X.value('CheckOutDate[1]', 'date') as CheckOutDate,
       R.X.value('NumberOfADT[1]', 'int') as NumberOfADT,
       R.X.value('count(CHD)', 'int') as CHDCount,
       stuff((select ';'+C.X.value('.', 'varchar(3)')
              from R.X.nodes('CHD/Age') as C(X)
              for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as CHDAges
from @XMLValue.nodes('/SearchQuery') as S(X)
  cross apply S.X.nodes('Room') as R(X)
```

Comment: do you have any idea how awesome guy you are? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This should get you close:

```
SELECT  ResortID = @xmlvalue.value('(//ResortID)[1]', 'int')
      , CheckInDate = @xmlvalue.value('(//CheckInDate)[1]', 'date')
      , CheckOutDate = @xmlvalue.value('(//CheckOutDate)[1]', 'date')
      , NumberOfAdt = Room.value('(NumberOfADT)[1]', 'INT')
      , CHDCount = Room.value('count(./CHD)', 'int')
      , CHDAges = Room.query('for $c in ./CHD
                        return concat(($c/Age)[1], ";")').value('(.)[1]',
                                                              'varchar(100)')
FROM    @XMLValue.nodes('/SearchQuery/Room') AS SearchQuery ( Room ) ;
```

Comment: d'oh; missed the page refresh :)

Comment: thanks! I already got it as you see but thanks for the effort :)